# If is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module

Tags: angular

I am implementing a angular 4 component and getting an error

If 'footer-bar' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
    If 'nav-bar' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.

I have imported the toolbar and navbar in the app.module. Not sure why I am getting the error

Navbar

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'nav-bar',
  templateUrl: './navbar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./navbar.component.css']
})
export class NavbarComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

Footerbar

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'footer-bar',
  templateUrl: './footerbar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./footerbar.component.css']
})
export class FooterbarComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

AppModule

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import {FormsModule} from '@angular/forms';
import {HttpModule} from '@angular/http'

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { NavbarComponent } from './navbar/navbar.component';
import { TopbarComponent } from './topbar/topbar.component';
import { FooterbarComponent } from './footerbar/footerbar.component';
import { MRDBGlobalConstants } from './shared/mrdb.global.constants';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    FooterbarComponent,
    TopbarComponent,
    NavbarComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpModule
  ],
  providers: [MRDBGlobalConstants],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Appcomponent

```
import { Component ,ViewContainerRef } from '@angular/core';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'app';

constructor(public viewRef : ViewContainerRef) {

}

}
```

Comment: How are you starting the server .  May be its not compiled ?

Comment: I am using angular-cli and running command ng serve on the command prompt

Comment: I checked again. It has resoved. One of my files werent saved hence it wasnt reflecting

Comment: yes seemed something like that because the code looked fine

Comment: yes, sometimes "ng serve" needs to be restarted, I have not figured out the reason yet, I am also new to the 'ng' environment.
if it fails with 'ng serve -prod --aot' you have explicitly say that you use the AOT (ahead of time compilation) in your question